# Ошибка миграции django-cms

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm, миграция, django-model

Создал таблицу doctors которая обращается к модели Title в django-cms. При миграции на сервере происходит ошибка которая в текстовом виде ниже. Много гуглил, ничего не помогло.
Я могу удалить все миграции из папки migrations и запустить makemigrations и оно сработает, но проблема в том что при изменении таблицы потом миграции не будут применяться.
Вот возникает вопрос, как я могу поправить данную ошибку что бы каждый раз не удалять миграции и не сбрасывать БД.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/user/Рабочий стол/backend-clinic/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/user/Рабочий стол/backend-clinic/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/user/Рабочий стол/backend-clinic/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/user/Рабочий стол/backend-clinic/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/user/Рабочий стол/backend-clinic/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/Рабочий стол/backend-clinic/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 92, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/home/user/Рабочий стол/backend-clinic/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/home/user/Рабочий стол/backend-clinic/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/user/Рабочий стол/backend-clinic/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 259, in build_graph
    self.graph.validate_consistency()
  File "/home/user/Рабочий стол/backend-clinic/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 195, in validate_consistency
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
  File "/home/user/Рабочий стол/backend-clinic/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 195, in <listcomp>
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
  File "/home/user/Рабочий стол/backend-clinic/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 58, in raise_error
    raise NodeNotFoundError(self.error_message, self.key, origin=self.origin)
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration doctors.0001_initial dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('cms', '0023_auto_20211110_1234')
```

**Немного разобрался с этой проблемой. Миграция под номером 0023 создается при создании миграций таблиц в которых есть ForeignKey на таблицу из django-cms, как решить эту проблему пока нет мысли. Жду вашей помощи.**

```bsh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 10853 ноя 15 17:30 0001_initial.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  8719 ноя 15 17:30 0002_auto_20140816_1918.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user   389 ноя 15 17:30 0003_auto_20140926_2347.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  1355 ноя 15 17:30 0004_auto_20140924_1038.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  4844 ноя 15 17:30 0005_auto_20140924_1039.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  1853 ноя 15 17:30 0006_auto_20140924_1110.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user   378 ноя 15 17:30 0007_auto_20141028_1559.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user   394 ноя 15 17:30 0008_auto_20150121_0059.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user   419 ноя 15 17:30 0008_auto_20150208_2149.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user   224 ноя 15 17:30 0009_merge.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  3223 ноя 15 17:30 0010_migrate_use_structure.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user   651 ноя 15 17:30 0011_auto_20150419_1006.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user   823 ноя 15 17:30 0012_auto_20150607_2207.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user   546 ноя 15 17:30 0013_urlconfrevision.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  1363 ноя 15 17:30 0014_auto_20160404_1908.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user   391 ноя 15 17:30 0015_auto_20160421_0000.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user   773 ноя 15 17:30 0016_auto_20160608_1535.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  1988 ноя 15 17:30 0017_pagetype.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  3490 ноя 15 17:30 0018_create_pagenode.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  3189 ноя 15 17:30 0019_set_pagenode.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  2730 ноя 15 17:30 0020_old_tree_cleanup.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user   427 ноя 15 17:30 0021_auto_20180507_1432.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user   810 ноя 15 17:30 0022_auto_20180620_1551.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  2384 ноя 15 17:37 0023_auto_20211115_1737.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user   395 ноя 15 17:30 __init__.py
drwxrwxr-x 2 user user  4096 ноя 15 17:30 __pycache__
```

```bsh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10853 Nov 15 17:36 0001_initial.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  8719 Nov 15 17:36 0002_auto_20140816_1918.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   389 Nov 15 17:36 0003_auto_20140926_2347.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1355 Nov 15 17:36 0004_auto_20140924_1038.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4844 Nov 15 17:36 0005_auto_20140924_1039.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1853 Nov 15 17:36 0006_auto_20140924_1110.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   378 Nov 15 17:36 0007_auto_20141028_1559.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   394 Nov 15 17:36 0008_auto_20150121_0059.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   419 Nov 15 17:36 0008_auto_20150208_2149.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   224 Nov 15 17:36 0009_merge.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3223 Nov 15 17:36 0010_migrate_use_structure.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   651 Nov 15 17:36 0011_auto_20150419_1006.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   823 Nov 15 17:36 0012_auto_20150607_2207.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   546 Nov 15 17:36 0013_urlconfrevision.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1363 Nov 15 17:36 0014_auto_20160404_1908.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   391 Nov 15 17:36 0015_auto_20160421_0000.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   773 Nov 15 17:36 0016_auto_20160608_1535.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1988 Nov 15 17:36 0017_pagetype.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3490 Nov 15 17:36 0018_create_pagenode.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3189 Nov 15 17:36 0019_set_pagenode.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2730 Nov 15 17:36 0020_old_tree_cleanup.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   427 Nov 15 17:36 0021_auto_20180507_1432.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   810 Nov 15 17:36 0022_auto_20180620_1551.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2384 Nov 10 12:34 0023_auto_20211110_1234.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   395 Nov 15 17:36 __init__.py
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Nov 15 17:36 __pycache__
```

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: есть подозрение что в миграции вы пытаетесь какое-то поле сделать foreign key, но какому-то заначению в табличке не соответствует записи с primary key.

Comment: Ошибка же в том что django не может найти зависимость для миграции, не думаю что ошибка в том что вы написали.

Comment: django-cms прописан в INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Прописано, я просто всё уже перепробовал, в крайнем случаю написал сюда

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Решил я проблему хоть и не очень правильно, но оно работает без ошибок. Я изменил название файла на локальной машине на название с сервера, то есть **0023_auto_20211115_1737.py** изменил на **0023_auto_20211110_1234.py**. Так же в БД на локальной машине в таблице django_migrations изменил запись где было name=0023_auto_20211115_1737.py, на name=0023_auto_20211115_1737.py.
2. Так же применял еще один вариант решения данной проблемы, который был не очень удобен, я просто убирал из файлов в коммите файлы которые ломали все миграции.